# Change in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`add_index :tests, [:title, :level], unique: true`
how can i change `title` to `body` and save in schema.rb
I tired to manually change it but it doesn't save in schema.rb

Answer (score 0):

You need to run again the migration.

Your schema version was already set to the id of your migration.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => MIGRATION_ID) do
  # schema definition ...
end
```

That's why even if you run all the migrations again nothing changes, because the version tells Active Record that it shouldn't run previous migrations than its version number.

You need to rollback your previous migration and then run migrations again.

```
rake db:rollback # it will rollback the last migration applied.
rake db:migrate
```

BTW this solution should be used only for development environment. If you want to change the production DB you should create another migration to change the column.